# GUI for tail for Linux

Tags: linux, gui, tail

Could someone recommend a graphical tail kind of document viewer? So that I could open a document, scroll up and down, etc. and that the document would refresh itself automatically (without prompting, freezing, etc). Ideally if it had a search functionality + give me a way to define highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

**MakeLogic Tail** is one. The download link is acting a bit strange though. I managed to get the source code but I'm not familiar with how to compile Java code.

Home: http://www.makelogic.com/tail/TailHome.htm 
Source: http://www.makelogic.com/downloads/MakeLogicTail2.1.0src.zip

### Update

Played around with the URL a bit and found the *jar* file. Could just be me but it didn't want to start downloading when linked directly to. I managed to still get it and uploaded it to MediaFire.
Executable *jar* file: http://www.mediafire.com/?koc791k2bjjlfqb

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MultiTail:

- http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/examples.html
- http://linuxgazette.net/issue95/vanheusden.html

It's "only" text mode, but it has features like scrolling, searching and color schemes.